# Remove middle part of string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, substring

How do I remove the middle part of a sting? 
For example, take the string - '2018_002.Feb'. 
For this example, I want to remove '002.', so that I get '2018_Feb'

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Try with `sub("\\d+\\.", "", str1)#[1] "2018_Feb"` or by convertting to date class `format(as.Date(str1, "%Y_0%d.%b"), "%Y_%b")`

Comment: related: [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Both the commands worked perfectly well. Thanks. 
Could you please just explain me how these commands worked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use the `stringr` package as opposed to the base r packages for string manipulations because I find the syntax for the functions more consistent.

```
library(stringr)

var = "2018_002.Feb"

str_replace(var, pattern = "_\\d+\\.", replacement = "_")

# [1] "2018_Feb"
```

With the `str_replace()` you are basically searching a pattern in the string an replacing it with something else. Often the replacement will just be an empty `""`, but in this case, it is easier to start the search where the function finds a `_` character because it is rather unique. From there you want to match on all the numbers that come after up to the period.

I recommend learning a bit about regular expression. The Basic Regular Expressions in R [Cheat Sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) is a good resource.

The regex for this problem reads something like this:

- first find `_` character that is followed by a number `\\d` and keep matching
  numbers `+` until you reach a period `\\.`
- Once you find this match "`_002.`", replace it with "`_`"

Hope that was comprehensible!

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem and I understood it completely.